# Найти алгоритм по соединению точек без пересечения линий

Tags: алгоритм

Заданы n произвольных точек на плоскости. Необходимо объединить все имеющиеся
точки замкнутой ломаной линией таким образом, чтобы она не имела самопересечений.
Входные данные:
Список произвольных координат точек на плоскости.
Выходные данные:
Список координат точек на плоскости, которые при последовательном соединении
образуют замкнутую ломаную линию, не имеющую самопересечений.

Comment: Нечетко сформулирована задача. Соединить одной ломаной? Замкнутой? нет? максимальным количеством непересекающихся отрезков? Словом, сформулируйте задачу поточнее...

Comment: Олимпиаду что-ль решаешь?

Comment: возможно, имеется в виду Триангуляция Делоне https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5 ?

Answer (score 6):

Код писать не буду. Идея:

1. найти точку которая точно будет внутри выпуклой оболочки (среднее по всем координатам например)
2. сдвинуть все координаты чтобы центр был в (0,0). Можно неявно.
3. Отсортировать все точки  сначала по полярному углу, при равенстве по модулю
4. Соединять точки начиная с самой первой именно в таком порядке.
5. Соединить 1 с последней

Тогда пересечение невозможно на 1 углу (там то по модулю) И на разных, т.к. мы сразу на ближайший идём.

P.S. сортируйте аккуратно) есть много гадких тестов на точность вычислений

Comment: у меня был вариане найти крайнюю точку по х-су а топом от нее вверх и в право плясать. Поделить точки на два массива: чточки что више по у-ку и точки что ниже от начальной точки. сначала прохожусть по верхних точках а потом по нижним, так чтобы ижние точки постепенно пришли к первой. но бывают моменти что одна точка "пробивает" линию и все ламается. можете подсказать есть ли  алгоритм,желательно написать, есть прямая с координатами и точка которая лежит  не на ней. как поределить что точка лежит под прамой.

Comment: @MaximBondarenko можно конечно соединять все точки сначала по x потом по y. Но в цикл не замкнёте. А если нужен цикл то моё решение одно из немногих правильных)

Comment: Не сработает на 4 точках на одной прямой (впрочем, в этом случае решения и нет, так что не вполне контрпример).

Comment: @VladD это единтсвуенная ситуация когда цикл не замыкается - 3 и более точки на 1 прямой, а других нет.

Comment: @pavel я кажись понял вашу мысль, хоть и не сразу, прощитаем все градусы углов от 0 до 360, потом мы по увеличению градуса угла будем соединять ети точки.

Comment: вот об этом я в поскриптуме предупредил) тут нельзя округлять углы. Угол - дробное число, но для сортировки можно (да и нужно) использовать целочисленное сравнение через тригонометрию (что-то в духе x1y2 > x2y1).