# Отрисовка не пересекающихся прямых

Tags: python, геометрия

Имеются 10 рандомных точек, надо построить максимально возможное количество соединений этих точек таким образом, чтобы отрезки не пересекались. Я уже пытался получить точки пересечения и на основе них отрисовать отрезки, однако правильная отрисовка не получается

```
for i in range(len(A)):
  x1_1=X[i]
  y1_1=Y[i]
  for j in range(len(A)):
     x1_2=X[j+1]
     y1_2=Y[j+1]
     for f in range(len(A)):
         x2_1=X[f]
         y2_1=Y[f]
         for g in range(len(A)):
            x2_2=X[g+1]
            y2_2=Y[g+1]
            A1=y1_1-y1_2
            B1=x1_2-x1_1
            A2=y2_1-y2_2
            B2=x2_2-x2_1
            D=A1*B2-A2*B1
            if D!=0:
                C1 = x1_1*y1_2 - x1_2*y1_1
                C2 = x2_1*y2_2 - x2_2*y2_1
                x=(B1*C2-B2*C1)/D
                y=(A2*C1-A1*C2)/D
```

Comment: "соединить эти точки **каждую с каждой** таким образом, чтобы полученные отрезки **не пересекались**" - прямыми линиями? А это вообще геометрически возможно?

Comment: я тоже думаю, что для больше двух евклидова геометрия не справится

Comment: Простите, не совсем четко сформулировал проблему

Comment: Я могу представить максимум для 4 (треугольник с 4й точкой в центре)

Comment: вот здесь что-то на эту тему - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/590415/Найти-алгоритм-по-соединению-точек-без-пересечения-линий

Comment: Благодарю Вас, однако это не совсем полностью решит проблему. Надо получить все возможные соединения, которые не имеют пересечения с другими отрезками

Comment: я понимаю, потому и написал "что-то на тему" :)

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. Вы уверены, что вас только параллельные прямые интересуют? Или вы имели в виду отрезки, а не прямые в заголовке? Вы хотите только попарные соединения или достаточно, чтобы путь был от одной точки к другой? Точки на плоскости, на сфере или в 3D? Что значит "отрисовка" Что вы ожидали ваш код должен делать? Что вместо этого происходит? Приведите явный пример. Картинка не помешает.

Comment: возможно, имеется в виду Триангуляция Делоне
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5 ?